# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ReactFireMixin' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting error after adding "reactfire" module in my code.
don't know what is the problem.
here is my code and error image attached.
maybe there is something wrong in usage of "ReactFireMixin".

```html
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Repose = require('./Github/Repose');
var UserProfile = require('./Github/UserProfile');
var Notes = require('./Notes/Notes');
var Repose = require('./Github/Repose');
var ReactFireMixin = require('reactfire');
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var Profile = React.createClass({
  mixins:[ReactFireMixin],
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      notes: [1,2,3],
      bio: {
        name: 'Ahmed'
      },
      repose: ['a','b','c']
    };
  },
  componentDidMount : function(){
    this.ref = new Firebase('https://github-note-taker-.firebaseio.com/');
    var childRef = this.ref.child(this.props.params.username);
    this.bingAsArray(childRef,'notes')
  },
  componentWillUnmount : function(){
    this.unbind('notes');
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        <div className="col-xs-4">
          <UserProfile username={this.props.params.username} bio={this.state.bio} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-4" >
          <Repose username={this.props.params.username} repose={this.state.repose} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-4">
          <Notes username={this.props.params.username} notes={this.state.notes} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Profile;
```

Screenshot of Console Error:

[image: Screenshot of Console Error]